# Using the constructor in the Driver

Tags: java, class, object

I created the class OCCStudent and I am using the driver OCCStudentDemo. I am trying to use the constructor method I defined for OCCStudent, but I am receiving an error saying that the constructor for OCCStudent is undefined. Here is the class:

```
public class OCCStudent {

// Define the instance variables (aka fields) for the class
// Data we want to store for each object we create
private String fullName;
private String userName;
private int age;
private String cNumber;
private double gPA;

// Define the constructor method
// Constructor instantiates (creates) new objects
public OCCStudent(String cNumber, String userName, String fullName,
        int age, double gPA) {

    // set each of the instance variables to the value coming into the user
    // Instance variables always start with this.****
    this.cNumber = cNumber;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.age = age;
    this.gPA = gPA;
}


// Let's define a copy constructor from other student:
public OCCStudent(OCCStudent otherStudent) {
    this.cNumber = otherStudent.cNumber;
    this.userName = otherStudent.userName;
    this.fullName = otherStudent.fullName;
    this.age = otherStudent.age;
    this.gPA = otherStudent.gPA;
}

// Let's define the toString() method
// Special method to print the object as a String(as text)
// By default use "CSV" format: Comma Separated Values
@Override
public String toString() {
    String output = this.cNumber + ", " + this.userName + ", "
            + this.fullName + ", " + this.age + ", " + this.gPA;
    return output;
}

// Define the equals method, which compares instance variables
// rather than memory locations
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    OCCStudent otherStudent = (OCCStudent) obj;
    // compare all the instance variables with the other student
    if (this.cNumber.equals(otherStudent.cNumber)
            && this.userName.equals(otherStudent.userName)
            && this.fullName.equals(otherStudent.fullName)
            && this.age == otherStudent.age && this.gPA == otherStudent.gPA)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

// Method to see if two students are the same age
public boolean isSameAge(OCCStudent otherStudent) {
    if (this.age == otherStudent.age)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public boolean isSameName(OCCStudent otherStudent) {
    if (this.fullName == otherStudent.fullName)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public boolean isSameUserName(OCCStudent otherStudent) {
    if (this.userName == otherStudent.userName)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public boolean isSameCnumber(OCCStudent otherStudent) {
    if (this.cNumber == otherStudent.cNumber)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public boolean isSameGpa(OCCStudent otherStudent) {
    if (this.gPA == otherStudent.gPA)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

// Accessors - return the value of an instance variable
public String getfullName() {
    return this.fullName;
}

public String getuserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public double getgPA() {
    return this.gPA;
}

public int getage() {
    return this.age;
}

// Mutators - change the value of an instance variable
public void setfullName(String newfullName) {
    this.fullName = newfullName;
}

public void setuserName(String newuserName) {
    this.userName = newuserName;
}
public void setgPA(double newgPA) {
    this.gPA = newgPA;
}
public void setage(int newage) {
    this.age = newage;
}

}
```

Then my driver using the constructor:

```
public class OCCStudentDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        OCCStudent student1 = new OCCStudent();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an existing constructor.

```
OCCStudent student1 = new OCCStudent();
```

does not exists the constructor is.

```
public OCCStudent(String cNumber, String userName, String fullName,
    int age, double gPA)
```

or

```
public OCCStudent(OCCStudent otherStudent)
```

hence in main you need to do something like

```
OCCStudent student1 = new OCCStudent("TheCNumber", "The usersname", "The fullName", 20,1.34);
```

once you have `student1` you can use the other constructor

```
OCCStudent student2 = new  OCCStudent(student1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right there is no constructor for `OCCStudent` with no parameter like the one you try to invoke.

You must either create a constructor with no parameter or use the first one:

```
 public OCCStudent(String cNumber, String userName, String fullName, int age, double gPA)
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is not going to insert a `default` constructor, when you have your own constructor and thats the reason you are getting compilation error.

Snippet from [jls constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is
>   implicitly declared.

Solution:

1. Either use the constructor which takes `OCCStudent`.
2. Create a no argument constructor.